# Menu hover effect - how to reproduce this effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, effects

Here is a nice hover effect applyied on main menu (red rectangles above menu): http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/37841.html

I'd like to use this effect on my website. There is no any css for that effect, so it must be some javascript used. How could I reproduce this or where could I find the javascript that can do that on my website? Simply, how could I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use javascript, you can achieve it via CSS, try toggling the hover state on any of those links and you will see the effect.

The relevant CSS there is

```
#superfish-1 > li > a {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    padding: 98px 10px 0 10px !important;
    background: url(../images/menu_hover.gif) 0 -100px repeat-x;
}

#superfish-1 a:hover {
      background-position: 0 0;
}
```

So, basically, there is a background image (the red rectangle) with a 100px offset; when you hover the link, the background offset disappears (with a 0.3s transition)

Answer (score 0):

The best language to use would be javascript and the library JQuery. Use the command .toggleSlide and .hover() I put some code down below as an example. Research more into it to get more advanced.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.home').hover(function(){
        $('#home_div').toggleSlide('slow');
    });
});
```

".home would" be the menu tab that say "Home"    
"#home_div" would be the red box that appears.
to summarize all the code: You are basically saying that when you hover over the html element with the class "home" (in the case the menu item) to have the html element with the id "home_div" to slide down slow. and then slide back once you stop hovering your mouse.  
Good luck. If you want to know more about jquery just research it.